# Get touch location in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, menu

I am showing `UIMenuController` using `UITableView` delegates,

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0){
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0){

    if(action == @selector(copy:)){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0){

    if(action == @selector(copy:)){
        NSLog(@"Action");

    }
}
```

But Is there any way to get the touch location in the `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Why do you need to know where the menu was presented from? There may be other solutions depending on your needs.

Comment: I want to show menuController on specified portions in UItableviewCell..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is: Create custom UITableViewCells which have clear (invisible) buttons over the "hot spots" you care about someone touching.